# Is there any perfect squares that are also binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Examining the Tartaglia's triangle, I have observed that all the squares were the trivial cases, that is, $\binom{n^2}1$ or $\binom{n^2}{n^2-1}$.

More formally:

**Conjecture**: If $\binom nm=k^2$ then $n=k^2$.

Is it known to be true?

I have tried to use the formula

$$\nu_p\left(m!\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac m{p^\alpha}\right\rfloor$$

to prove that the exponents of the factorization of the binomial coefficients are odd, but I realized that this cannot be proved, because the binomial coefficients needn't be square-free: $\binom 63=20$, for example.

Any ideas?

Comment: For $C(n, 2)= m^2$, you get a Pell equation with infinite solutions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is well known that the equation 
$$
\binom{n}{k}=m^{\ell}
$$
has no integer solutions with $ℓ ≥ 2$ and $4 ≤ k ≤ n − 4$.
For $k=3$ and $\ell=2$ we only have the solution $\binom{50}{3}=140^2$, and for
$k=\ell=2$ there are more. This is due to Erdős. For details see "Binomial coefficients are (almost) never powers" in [the
book of proofs by Aigner and Ziegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK).

Comment: Since you were keen to do it right, I inserted the ő for you ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: thank you !

Comment: The $k=l=2$ case comes down to [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) as you must have $\frac 12n(n-1)$ a square.  An example is ${9 \choose 2}=36$