# To find positive integers $n$ such that $\dfrac {n(n+1)(n+2)}6$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How many positive integers $n$ are there such that $\dfrac {n(n+1)(n+2)}6$ is a perfect square ? I know $n=1 , 2$ works ; are there any more ? Are there only finitely many such $n$ ?

Comment: Related: [When is $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6$ a perfect cube?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345732)

Comment: @barto : looks similar ,  but really related ?!?

Comment: I think that it's just the two.  Notice that n$ (n+1) and (n+2) can have no common factors apart from 2.  So all prime factors of 3 or higher need all be grouped into a single term of the product.  I can finish it with case bashing, but it's not particularly elegant.

Comment: @Maciek : Just to make it more non-elegant ; I think $n=48$ also works ...

Comment: The answer to this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778233/is-there-any-perfect-squares-that-are-also-binomial-coefficients) tells us that there are no solutions other than $n=1,2,48$. Since your equation is $\binom{n+2}{3}=m^2$.

Comment: @Pjotr5: This is a complete answer; if you post it as an answer, the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: This is related to the sum of the first $k$ squares being a square. Suppose $\frac 16 k(k+1)(2k+1)=r^2$ then, with $n=2k$ we have $\frac 16 n(n+2)(n+1)=4r^2=m^2$ - and the only non-trivial solution to that is $k=24$.

Answer (score 5):

Your equation is the same as finding integer solutions to the equation
$$
\binom{n+2}{3}=m^2.
$$

The top answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778233/is-there-any-perfect-squares-that-are-also-binomial-coefficients) tells us that there are only solutions for $n\in\{1,2,48\}$.