# are there known cases where $\binom{n}{k}$ is a perfect prime power?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I was wondering about cases where $\binom{n}{k}=p^j$ with $p$ a prime (nontrivially, so that $ n-k>1$ and $n \neq p^j$.) I had the terrible idea of checking binomial expansions
$$(x+y)^n \equiv x^n+y^n.$$

Upon some further googling, I learned that $\binom{50}{3}=140^2$, which means that this *can* occur for composite numbers.

Are there any ways that one can use primeness to argue that this will not occur? Or, are there any known counterexamples in which $\binom{n}{k}$ is a prime power?

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comments, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778233/is-there-any-perfect-squares-that-are-also-binomial-coefficients) answers the question for cases of $j \geq 2$ and $4 \leq k \leq n-4$.

The main answer mentions that there are examples where $k=j=2$, are any among these solutions with $p$ a prime?

[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778233/is-there-any-perfect-squares-that-are-also-binomial-coefficients) gives a negative answer for $p=2$ with $n-k \geq 2$.

I suppose there is only one question left then: can the theorem be strengthened to contain the extreme cases with the assumption that $p>2$ is a prime.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778233/is-there-any-perfect-squares-that-are-also-binomial-coefficients). For $p=2$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338488/binomial-coefficients-that-are-powers-of-2).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you very much! Both links were really interesting. I thankfully have a copy of proofs from the book, so I was able to locate the proof (although I haven't gone through it carefully.)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I hope I'm not missing anything, but there is still something to say here. Namely, for cases of $p>2$, the additional assumption of primeness *could* in principle strengthen the result. Are there results known in this way?

Comment: Let $K:=\max \{ k, n-k \} $. Then the interval $[K,n]$, should not contaion any prime number.

Comment: @Famke that is the behavior we should suspect (I'm actually not so sure of this?), so maybe no solution for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any perfect squares that are also binomial coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778233/is-there-any-perfect-squares-that-are-also-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos have you read my edits? That question is linked, I have further questions.

Comment: @AndresMejia You are right.

Comment: If ${n\choose 2}=p^j$ then $n(n-1)=2p^j$. Since the numbers $n$ and $n-1$ are relatively prime, one of then is divisible by $p^j$. Then the other is $1$ or $2$, thus $n\le 3$. So $n=3=p^j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erdos proved (in 1951) the stronger result that $\binom{n}{k}$ is never a perfect power if $k > 3$ (assuming that $n \geq 2k$ as we may). His argument is completely elementary -- see https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1951-05.pdf.

For $k=2$ and $k=3$, the case of possible prime powers is easily treated by divisibility arguments. The more general situation of arbitrary perfect powers for these values of $k$ was handled by Gyory in 1997 (in Acta Arithmetica), by a rather more complicated proof.

Comment: Could you give some hint as to what Gyory's results were? In your first sentence of the second paragraph, you mean to say that this is a negative result (can't be written as a prime power)?

Comment: The equation $\binom{n}{k}=y^j$ has no solutions (assuming that $n \geq 2k$) if either $k \geq 4$, or if $k \in \{ 2, 3 \}$ and $j \geq 3$. If $k=3$ and $j=2$, the only solution is $n=50$, $y=140$. If $k=j=2$, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: These rexults were already known (see the linked question in the OP.) The question is if you require that $y$ is prime, the result can be strengthened.

Comment: Well, as I said, then remaining case where $k=j=2$ is essentially trivial to treat via divisibility arguments for prime powers, so what question are you asking?

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry, I'm not sure why your main point was so opaque to me. Thank you